# I can not run my application in tomcat 7 with myfaces 2.0.13 and richfaces 4.0 final

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I have deployed my web application which heavily uses richfaces 4.0 final components sucessfully in tomcat 7 with myfaces 2.0.13(JSF 2.0 imp). But when I try to run my application I am constantly getting the following exception(The same application used to run sucessfully on tomcat 6 with Mojarra 2.0 ) :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:350)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:191)
    org.apache.myfaces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl.<init>(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:129)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:326)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:191)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:112)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:338)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:191)
    org.apache.myfaces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl.<init>(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:129)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:326)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:191)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:112)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.richfaces.context.FileUploadPartialViewContextFactory.<init>(FileUploadPartialViewContextFactory.java:77)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:338)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:191)
    org.apache.myfaces.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl.<init>(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:129)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:326)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:286)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:191)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:112)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1812)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.
```

I would be happy if someone helps me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have shifted to richfaces 4.2 and everything works fine. And i am satisfied with the result. So thanks. I guess that there is a bug with richfaces 4.0 final(fileUploader).